# index out of range when filling a slice

Tags: go, indexing, slice, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a Go function that reads from a csv, stores the lines into a struct object and then stores each struct object in an array of structs:

```
 type Asset struct {
        Id    string `json:"id"`
        Color string `json:"color"`
        Owner string `json:"owner"`
    }


func main() {
    csvFile, err := os.Open("assets.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened CSV file")
    defer csvFile.Close()

    //Read csv into an object
    csvLines, err := csv.NewReader(csvFile).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var assts []Asset
    i := 0
    //Read CSV lines and put them into an object. Then read from the object
    for _, line := range csvLines {
        asst := Asset{
            Id:    line[0],
            Color: line[1],
            Owner: line[2],
        }
        assts[i] = asst
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

But I keep on getting this error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

In the line: assts[i] = asst

Is this not the correct way to store an object in an array of structs?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, that's not an array. It's a slice.

Comment: Second, you can't assign to index `i` of a slice that has no elements. Use [`append()`](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15). I.e.: `assts = append(assets, asst)`. Another option is to pre-allocate the necessary size of the slice: i.e. `assts = make([]Asset, len(csvLines)`

Comment: You declare an unallocated slice (which will have the value `nil`): `var assts []Asset` and then go on setting elements using indices in a loop—but the slice is not even allocated, that is, has no storage for the data. Please start with [The Tour](https://tour.golang.org) and the move on to [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) (at least).

Comment: Further reading: <https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro> and <https://blog.golang.org/slices> (in that order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a `lice` (named as `assts`) and you are using it like and array.
With slice you have to use the `append` method.
With array (that have a fixed length) you can use index to assign a value to a
particular position, or the `append` method.
NOTE: If you use `append` on an array, you are going to increase the array length of the number of elements that you are going to add. This means that you are going to add your elements AFTER the max index of the array.

You can use the following code in order to read the CSV.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    csvutils "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/csv"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Asset struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Color string `json:"color"`
    Owner string `json:"owner"`
}

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("assets.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    headers, csvData := csvutils.ReadCSV(data, ',')
    var assets []Asset = make([]Asset, len(csvData))
    fmt.Println("The csv file have the following headers: ", headers)

    for i, line := range csvData {
        asst := Asset{
            Id:    line[0],
            Color: line[1],
            Owner: line[2],
        }
        assets[i] = asst
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! This was really helpful.